# Html Agility Pack - Get html fragment from an html document

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

Using the html agility pack; how would I extract an html "fragment" from a full html document? For my purposes, an html "fragment" is defined as all content inside of the `<body>` tags.

**For example:**

**Sample Input:**

```
<html>
   <head>
     <title>blah</title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <p>My content</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Desired Output:**

```
<p>My content</p>
```

Ideally, I'd like to return the content unaltered if it didn't contain an `<html>` or `<body>` element (eg. assume that I was passed a fragment in the first place if it wasn't a full html document)

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to do it in pieces.

you can do selectnodes of document for body or html as follows

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body") // returns body with entire contents :)
```

then you can check for null values for criteria and if that is provided, you can take the string as it is.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 6):

The following will work:

```
public string GetFragment(HtmlDocument document)
{
   return doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body") == null ? doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml : doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body").InnerHtml;
}
```