# Extracting an html fragment from an html document

Tags: c#, html, vb.net, text

I'm looking for an efficient means of extracting an html "fragment" from an html document. My [first implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348520/html-agility-pack-get-html-fragment-from-an-html-document) of this used the Html Agility Pack. This appeared to be a reasonable way to attack this problem, until I started running the extraction on large html documents - performance was very poor for something so trivial (I'm guessing due to the amount of time it was taking to parse the entire document).

Can anyone suggest a more efficient means of achieving my goal?

**To summarize:**

1. For my purposes, an html "fragment"
   is defined as all content inside of
   the `<body>` tags of an html
   document
2. Ideally, I'd like to return the
   content unaltered if it didn't
   contain an `<html>` or `<body>`
   (I'll assume I was passed an html
   fragment to begin with)
3. I have the entire html document available in memory (as a string), I won't be streaming it on demand - so a potential solution won't need to worry about that.
4. Performance is critical, so a potential solution should account for this.

**Sample Input:**

```
<html>
   <head>
     <title>blah</title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <p>My content</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Desired Output:**

```
<p>My content</p>
```

A solution in C# or VB.NET would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most html is not going to be XHTML compliant.  I would do an HTTP get request and search the resultant text for `.Contains("<body>")` and `.Contains("</body>")`.  You can use these two locations as your start and stop indexes for a reader stream.  Outside the body tag you really don't need to worry about XML compliance.

Comment: I guess I should have been more clear in my question; we can assume I have the entire html document string in memory; so I won't be streaming it on demand. I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: +1.  This is by far the absolute fastest way to do what the OP wants.    And you don't need a reader stream.  Just a regular string containing the HTML will work just fine.

Comment: This seems like a very reasonable approach, I'll give this a shot later on today.

Comment: This gave great performance results compared to my original implementation; perhaps not as safe - but that wasn't the goal here.

Answer (score 0):

You could hack it using a [WebBrowse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control and take advantage of `webBrowser1.document` property (though not sure what you're trying to accomplish).

Comment: Brad, I'm assuming that's not going to be much faster than going the Html Agility Pack route; I'm looking for a performant solution here, likely involving directly manipulating the text I'm given.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, I did something similar in the past with an `XPathNavigator`. I think it looked something like this:

```
        XPathDocument xDoc = new System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument(new StringReader(content));
        XPathNavigator xNav = xDoc.CreateNavigator();
        XPathNavigator node = xNav.SelectSingleNode("/body");
```

where you could change `/body` to whatever you need to look for.

Comment: This is a good way, but you must be very very careful that your HTML is XHTML compliant and doesn't include annoying unclosed tags specifically like <img src='myimage.png'>.

Comment: This looks like a reasonable solution (I'll need to test performance to be sure), but as Tom as noted; I may not be able to assume the html I'm given is XHTML compliant.

Comment: True; I know I had a situation where I had to add a root node to make my input compliant, but I was able to make it work.